# Chokidar runs on console but doesn't work when called via 'npm run'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, chokidar

i've added a script to watch over Tailwind CSS files with Chokidar. Now its working when i call the command in the cli using `chokidar 'tailwind.config.js' --initial=true -c 'npm run build-tailwind'`. It works perfectly and runs the corresponding command on change, but when i use it in my package json like so

```
"watch-tailwind": "chokidar 'tailwind.config.js' --initial=true -c 'npm run build-tailwind'",
```

and call it via `npm run watch-tailwind`.

```
$ npm run watch-tailwind

> bloodline@0.0.1 watch-tailwind C:\xampp\htdocs\bloodline
> chokidar 'tailwind.config.js' --initial=true -c 'npm run build-tailwind'

Watching "'tailwind.config.js'", "run", "build-tailwind'" ..
```

And when i modify the `tailwind.config.js` file it remains the same and it wont trigger the update. The text remains the same in cli. When in reality it should have added some extra lines like so

```
change:tailwind.config.js

> bloodline@0.0.1 build-tailwind C:\xampp\htdocs\bloodline
> postcss src/renderer/assets/scss/tailwind/tailwind.scss -o src/renderer/assets/scss/tailwind/_build.scss
```

But the files dont change nor it does anything. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but there's a weird issue with single quotations in windows 10, so i changed

```
"watch-tailwind": "chokidar 'tailwind.config.js' --initial=true -c 'npm run build-tailwind'",
```

to

```
"watch-tailwind": "chokidar \"tailwind.config.js\" --initial=true -c \"npm run build-tailwind\"",
```

and it fixed the problem.